# How to hide measure in Cube browser?

Tags: ssas, cube

I have 3 measures in CUBE Structure tab

I dont want to show one of them while I am browsing the cube,but,all of them are there.

I tried to find a way to hide them,but failed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a setting to make an entire Measure Group invisible - but you may want to try setting all the underlying measures to visible=false and see if that in turn makes the Group invisible.

You could also consider using a Perspective - that lets you show/hide objects.

Is this a security related issue?